# When I try to enter info from a form to SQL I get an error where the table name is duplicated

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a Form which will import data into a SQL Database but when I fill in the information, I get such an error:

> Error: INSERT INTO andrea22_search (Name, TodayDate, ProjectNumber, Area, DoneBefore, HaveChangesMade, SafeAccess, ElectricalEquipment, MachineGuarding, CorrectEquipment, SDS, ControlToxic, PPE, Hazard, OtherHazard, ControlHazard, MonitorProcess, AdditionalComments) VALUES ('Andi', '2017-01-03','32a','AS','Yes','No','N/A','Yes','No','N/A','Yes','No','','','','Yes','')
>   Table 'andrea22_search.andrea22_search' doesn't exist

If I look at the code in my submit.php file I don't see where the *andrea22_search.andrea22_search* comes from. This error of course prevents me from adding data to the Database.

```
$dbname = "andrea22_search";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$name = $_POST['input4'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$projectnumber = $_POST['input1'];
$area   = $_POST['input2'];
$donebefore = $_POST['radio9'];
$changesmade    = $_POST['radio8'];
$safeaccess = $_POST['radio11'];
$electrical = $_POST['radio5'];
$machineguarding    = $_POST['radio6'];
$correctequipment   = $_POST['radio4'];
$sds    = $_POST['radio3'];
$controltoxic   = $_POST['radio1'];
$ppe    = $_POST['checkbox[]'];
$otherhazards   = $_POST['input3'];
$controlofhazards   = $_POST['checkbox1[]'];
$monitor    = $_POST['radio12'];
$comments   = $_POST['input'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO search (Name, TodayDate, ProjectNumber, Area, DoneBefore, HaveChangesMade, SafeAccess, ElectricalEquipment, MachineGuarding, CorrectEquipment, SDS, ControlToxic, PPE, Hazard, OtherHazard, ControlHazard, MonitorProcess, AdditionalComments) VALUES ('$name', '$date','$projectnumber','$area','$donebefore','$changesmade','$safeaccess','$electrical','$machineguarding','$correctequipment','$sds','$controltoxic','$ppe','$otherhazards','$controlofhazards','$monitor','$comments')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You're wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Ok, how can I avoid that --- as an addition to my original question

Comment: You can start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Nothing in the code suggests that `$sql` would be changed mid-way; have you shown us the entire code?